# Replace name attr with current name + another string with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var prodElem = $('#dropTitle').text();

$(prodElem).clone(true, true).appendTo('#orders')
 .attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + "-1");
```

but the name attribute is being replaced by **-1**.

How can I utilize "this" in order to achieve the current name and append -1 to the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in that code doesn't refer to the element(s) you're setting the name on. My guess is this code is running where `this` refers to `window`, and so `$(this).attr("name")` returns the window name (which is usually blank), so you're setting `name` on all of those elements to `"" + "-1"`, which is of course, `"-1"`.

You can use [the version of `attr` that accepts a callback](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function):

```
$(prodElem).clone(true, true).appendTo('#orders')
  .attr("name", function() {
    return $(this).attr("name") + "-1";
  });
```

There, `this` refers to each matching element.

Side note: If this is really the `name` attribute, it's reflected by the property `name`, so you could also do it with `prop` and get the reflected attribute directly in the function:

```
$(prodElem).clone(true, true).appendTo('#orders')
  .prop("name", function() {
    return this.name + "-1";
  });
```

Comment: But in question `prodElem` is simple text.

Comment: @RohitSharma - Right, and then that's passed into `$()`. I'm assuming the text is a selector of some kind. (But it **is** an assumption, quite right.)

Comment: You are correct with the assumption, my bad, thank you very much